# The DHT in JPEG does not contain the actual huffman code, how come?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, signal-processing

The DHT contains 16 bytes that just contains count of how many values were encoded with huffman code of each length from 1 bit all the way to 16 bits. After this, it contains the actual values that were encoded, all these value are 8 bits in size.

Q: Why is huffman code not stored, how does decoder derive the codes?

Q: If there are say 4 values that have huffman code of 3 bits long, we shall write them as 4 bytes. Does it matter what order they are in or they have to be in ascending or descending order? I do know that the values must be in order such that the values with 1 bit huffman code are then followed by values with 2 bit huffman code e.t.c.

Q: I have used jpegsnoop to look at huffman table of different files, some made in MS paint and some were downloaded. I find that they all have the SAME table.

Here are the DHT entries I got from JPEG snoop:

```
  Destination ID = 1
  Class = 1 (AC Table)
    Codes of length 01 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 02 bits (002 total): 00 01 
    Codes of length 03 bits (001 total): 02 
    Codes of length 04 bits (002 total): 03 11 
    Codes of length 05 bits (004 total): 04 05 21 31 
    Codes of length 06 bits (004 total): 06 12 41 51 
    Codes of length 07 bits (003 total): 07 61 71 
    Codes of length 08 bits (004 total): 13 22 32 81 
    Codes of length 09 bits (007 total): 08 14 42 91 A1 B1 C1 
    Codes of length 10 bits (005 total): 09 23 33 52 F0 
    Codes of length 11 bits (004 total): 15 62 72 D1 
    Codes of length 12 bits (004 total): 0A 16 24 34 
    Codes of length 13 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 14 bits (001 total): E1 
    Codes of length 15 bits (002 total): 25 F1 
    Codes of length 16 bits (119 total): 17 18 19 1A 26 27 28 29 2A 35 36 37 38 39 3A 43 
                                         44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 63 
                                         64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 82 
                                         83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
                                         9A A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 
                                         B8 B9 BA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA D2 D3 D4 D5 
                                         D6 D7 D8 D9 DA E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA F2 F3 
                                         F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA 
    Total number of codes: 162
```

And

```
  Destination ID = 1
  Class = 0 (DC / Lossless Table)
    Codes of length 01 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 02 bits (003 total): 00 01 02 
    Codes of length 03 bits (001 total): 03 
    Codes of length 04 bits (001 total): 04 
    Codes of length 05 bits (001 total): 05 
    Codes of length 06 bits (001 total): 06 
    Codes of length 07 bits (001 total): 07 
    Codes of length 08 bits (001 total): 08 
    Codes of length 09 bits (001 total): 09 
    Codes of length 10 bits (001 total): 0A 
    Codes of length 11 bits (001 total): 0B 
    Codes of length 12 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 13 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 14 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 15 bits (000 total): 
    Codes of length 16 bits (000 total): 
    Total number of codes: 012
```

The AC table compresses RRRRSSSS that contain zero-run length and AC coefficient magnitude while the DC table compresses SSSS. Thus, I think that the AC table must contain total of 255 entries (exlcuded 0) while the DC table must be 15 entries (excluded 0). However, neither of the tables contain this many total number of codes. WHY?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Why is huffman code not stored, how does decoder derive the codes?

The reason the Huffman tables is defined as they are rather than with the actual codes is that it is much smaller and simpler to encode that way. PNG uses a similar but different method.

Keep in mind that to store the Huffman codes in the JPEG stream you would need to include both the length and the code itself. The result would be much larger than encoding a count of lengths.

> Q: If there are say 4 values that have huffman code of 3 bits long, we shall write them as 4 bytes. Does it matter what order they are in or they have to be in ascending or descending order?

If the Huffman code has 3 bits, it is written as three bits to the JPEG stream. The codes are generated in ascending order.

> Q: I have used jpegsnoop to look at huffman table of different files, some made in MS paint and some were downloaded. I find that they all have the SAME table.

The encoder is being lazy and using a fixed Huffman table. There is a sample Huffman table in the JPEG standard that they often use. To generate optimal Huffman codes, the encoder must make two passes over the data. With a preset table, the encoder only needs to make one pass.

Comment: The huffman table in annex k of itu t.81 has all possible values to be encoded. However, in the tables above, there are less than 256 entries for ac and less than 16 for dc. Why? I don't think that a continuous tone image can can be compressed with missing codes.

Comment: Yes, but in a continuous tone image, all sort of pixels will appear and that shall need all values of ssss and rrrrssss

Comment: R and S are just 4 bits.

Comment: Yes but for AC, we have an 8 bit field RRRRSSSS that will have values 0 to FFh

Comment: That's 256 possible values.

Answer (score 1):

F.1.2.1.2 and F.1.2.2.1 of the [JPEG Specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) explain why the Huffman tables are not fully populated.  For baseline encoding DC difference values are limited to 11 bits (table F.1) and AC values are limited to 10 bits (table F.2).

Since DC Huffman symbols only need SSSS values from 0 to 11 their Huffman trees need only 12 codes as you've reported.

AC Huffman symbols have a prefix zero run count from 0 to 15.  With 11 bit sizes that works out to 16 * 11 = 176 symbols.  However, they don't include the symbols 0x10, 0x20, ... 0xE0 because they are redundant.  They encode a run of 1, 2, ... 14 zeros followed by a 0 value.  If an encoder has, say, 7 zero values followed by a 3 bit value it can encode that as 0x73.  There would be no point encoding it with two symbols 0x60;0x03.

Ignoring those 14 useless symbols we end up with 162 codes as you have reported.

By the way, the 0xF0 (ZRL) value is needed because there isn't a symbol that can express a run of 16 zeros followed by a value thus is cannot be merged.

I don't know why the JPEG spec limits the DC and AC values to a certain number of bits.  I speculate that the extra precision would have no effect or is typically thrown away by quantization.  Or maybe it has to do with the mathematics of the Inverse Discrete Cosine Transform.  Keep in mind that these Huffman encoded values are (quantized) coefficients for the IDCT and are only indirectly related to the continuous tone RGB output.

Answer (score 0):

The Huffman encoding is almost fully determined by the relative frequencies of all 256 symbols (except tiebreaker rules). This means you can choose many, many formats to encode those relative frequencies; the most simple one would be to simply store all these frequencies. The receiver can then rebuild the encoding from that order.

Background: the two least frequent characters of a Huffman encoding share the same (long) prefix, and differ only in the last bit. This combination is then assigned a joint frequency (sum of both combinations), which is used recursively to determine the prefix. Finally, you end up with two sets, one holding X characters and the other holding 256-X characters. The first set has prefix 0 and the second set has prefix 1.

Yes, that's arbitrary, you could swap those 0 and 1, and have a similar table and the same compression ratio - a 0 is just as long as a one. That's why you have detailed rules (e.g. most common set gets 0, tiebreaker is first byte in set)

Back to encoding. You want to store these relative frequencies efficiently, as we're using compression here. Now, as I pointed out, when we have codes suffix-0 and suffix-1, they're both equally long (namely the suffix length plus one). So we know from the fact that there are 119 unique 16 bits codes that there are 60 unique prefixes with length 15. Calculating backwards, we also know that there are two unique symbols with length 15, total 62, so there must be 31 prefixes of length 14. We can backtrack again to prefixes of length 1.

Again, it's necessary to point out that we don't know here the exact values of those prefixes, and the matching symbols. This depends on the tiebreaker rules, as pointed out, but those rules are fixed for JPEG.

JPEG does have a bit of a special case: Huffman codes for very rare symbols *should* be longer than 16 bits. That's inconvenient, so in building the table you don't choose the two sets with the least combined frequency if either of them already has a long suffix - combining those two subsets would just make the suffix even longer. You see this with all the 16-bit codes in the example: most should have had longer codes in a pure Huffman encoding.

I think the worst case is if the most frequent character appears 50%, the next 25%, etc. You'll get codes 0, 10, 110, 1110 etcetera. That's unary counting, which is indeed optimal for that case, but the longest code is now 256 bits. You'd need a document with 2^256 bytes to have a frequency of 2^-256, though.